# Unity animator makes object reverse gravity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to follow the "John Lemon's Haunted Jaunt" tutorial, and when I added the rigidbody and checked use gravity, John Lemon started going up. After a little bit I figured out that the animator is what is causing this. When root motion is checked, John starts going down. when its disabled, gravity works normally. It I get rid of the animator controller, gravity works normally. I tried using a different animator controller, and the same thing happens. This happens when I use normal update mode and unscaled time update mode, and when i use animated physics update mode gravity just doesnt work, unless I set it to a higher mass, but if i do that it wont accelerate, it just stays at the same speed.
Another thing, in animate physics mode if i make the object's mass less than 1, it starts going up (still at a fixed speed and not accelerating). In normal mode and unscaled time mode, I can increase the mass and it slows it down a tiny bit, and it speeds up if i make it less than 1, but this is still not accelerating. It is also far less of an increase than if gravity worked normally.
One final thing, in normal and unscaled time mode, the rigidbody info shows a speed of 0, but the world center of mass (and the objects pos) keep decreasing. What the hell is happening here, and how do i fix it

Answer (score -1):

Try enabling the animator before animation, and disable it right after. And at start set it to disabled. So at times of no animation the animator is disabled.

I ran into an issue with the animator, apparently it locks the values used by the animators animations. This might be your problem too, check here [Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/animator-locking-animated-value-even-when-current-state-has-no-curves-keys-for-that-value.440363/page-2#post-6463009)

Comment: so only enable the animator when i want to play an animation? the problem is its supposed to always be animated, plus gravity still wont work when the object is being animated. also, if it locks the position values, why is my object going up in normal and unscaled time?

Comment: Im not sure how to solve it, but make the object you want to animate a child of an object, and let the parent have the rigidbody and gravity, or am I thinking wrong? :p